# erro inserir dados no banco php

Tags: php, mysql

estou fazendo uma pagina em html com os checkbox para inserir em forma de string dentro de uma linha da tabela, porem se eu nao marco todas as opçoes ele da um erro (mas insere no banco), como faço para sumir esse erro se no caso eu escolher apenas um valor da checkbox?

> Notice: Undefined index: plastico in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC\postagem.php on line 4
>   Notice: Undefined index: papelao in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC\postagem.php on line 5

```
include_once("setting.php");
$plastico = $_POST ['plastico'];
$papelao = $_POST ['papelao'];
$metal = $_POST['metal'];
$madeira = $_POST['madeira'];
$vidro = $_POST['vidro'];

$array = array ($plastico, $papelao, $metal, $madeira, $vidro);

foreach ($array as $key => $valor) {
    $campo[]= $valor;
    //echo $campo."<br/>";
}
$teste = implode(',',$campo);

 try{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO postagens (descricao) VALUES ('$teste')";
  echo $sql;
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);

    if ($linhas ==1){
        echo "registro gravado com sucesso";
    }else{
        echo "falha na gravaçao";
    }
```

Comment: Primeiramente não é ERRO e sim um AVISO, o que está ocorrendo é que você não está enviando no POST os campos "plastico" e nem "papelao".

Comment: sim, me expressei errado, tem como retirar a mensagem caso eu não escolha uma das opções do checkbox?

Comment: Coloque em cima de seu código: error_reporting (0);

Comment: Sua variável não foi iniciada, se não quer dar importância para isso, revise o error_reporting da sua hospedagem, ou force seu php.ini ou .htaccess a não exibir isso, você só precisa saber qual modo roda o interpretador no servidor para alterar os NOTICES, que não são erros. Mas é bom você começar a criar variáveis definidas ou tratá-las antes de usá-las para evitar os NOTICES.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que as vars quando inexistentes sejam por exemplo 0, você pode fazer o seguinte: checar se elas existem e se não, defini-las como 0, este erro ocorre pois voce ta tentando pegar um post que não existe

```
if (isset($_POST['opcao'])) 
     $var = $_POST['opcao']; else
     $var = 0;
```

assim, se não tiver um valor,ele será 0

Answer (score 0):

> Esse tipo de aviso `Notice: Undefined index:` é causado porque você tentou chamar uma variável $_POST que não foi enviada através do formulário.

Com esse esquema só retornarão os que estiverem marcados

HTML

coloque todos os `name` dos `checkbox` como `material[]`. Esses colchetes tratam os elementos do mesmo nome como um array

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="material[]" value="plastico" />plastico<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="material[]" value="papelao" />papelao<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="material[]" value="metal" />metal<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="material[]" value="madeira" />madeira<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="material[]" value="vidro" />vidro<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

PHP

```
if ((isset($_POST["material"])) && (!empty($_POST["material"]))){
    $opcoes = $_POST["material"];
    $materiais = implode( ",", $_POST['material'] );

    echo $materiais;

// ....
//..... "INSERT INTO postagens (descricao) VALUES ('$materiais')";


}
```

Answer (score -1):

O seu erro se refere ao espaço entre o `$_POST` e os colchetes para estes 2 índices, troque

```
$plastico = $_POST ['plastico']; por $plastico = $_POST['plastico'];
$papelao = $_POST ['papelao']; por $papelao = $_POST['papelao'];
```